# When Building C++ Eclipse Project in Cygwin, How do I remove the "make.exe" path

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, bash, cygwin

I am using Windows 7 64bit OS and have installed Cygwin64 (2.8.91).  I am running Eclipse Oxygen from both Windows and within a Cygwin bash Windows.  The Eclipse running in the Windows environment is able to build the library and application fine.  The Eclipse running in the Cygwin environment fails when trying to launch the "make.exe" as part of the build and clean process:

> 11:39:12 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project VectorMathLibTestCygWin ****
>      "C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe" all 
>      Cannot run program "C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe": Access is denied.

The output in the console for the Eclipse running on Windows does not include the path for the make.exe:

> 12:06:40 **** Incremental Build of configuration Win-Debug for project VectorMathLibTest ****
>      make all 
>      make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.

The make.exe can be invoked from the Cygwin bash shell on the command line:

> $ make -v
>      GNU Make 4.2.1
>      Built for x86_64-unknown-cygwin
>      Copyright (C) 1988-2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
>      License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
>      This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
>      There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

When using a fully qualified path, it fails:

> $ C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe -v
>      -bash: C:cygwin64binmake.exe: command not found
>
> The Eclipse .log shows a similar error:
>      java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe": Access is denied.

How can I configure Eclipse Build Properties to NOT add the path prefix to the "make.exe"?

Comment: Alternatively - what if you launch Cygwin and Eclipse with Administrative privileges?

Comment: I was able to run "C:\cygwin64\bin\make.exe -v" from the Administrator login to Cygwin (bash shell).  Corporate policy won't allow me to work as administrator.  Are there specific access rights that I need to assign to "C:\cygwin64\bin" (windows) or "\bin" (Cygwin)?

Comment: It looks like the problem is related to the "direction of the slash"

Comment: Well, normally cygwin, I dont know kind of mimics windows so c:\ is really /cygdrive/c/ so anyway you can change Eclipse to use /cygdrive/c/bin/make.exe On permissions, I'm not sure but might be worth a try to have your sys admins temporarily change that bind folder to be accessible by all users, especially yourself

Comment: Eclipse is not a cygwin application so it will not understand the `/cygdrive` prefix